# Class inherits generic dictionary<string, IFoo> and Interface

Tags: c#, generics, collections, interface

I have a class that inherits a generic dictionary and an inteface

```
public class MyDictionary: Dictionary<string, IFoo>, IMyDictionary
{
}
```

the issue is that consumers of this class are looking for the '.Keys' and ".Values" properties of the interface so i added:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    ICollection<string> Keys { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerable<IFoo> Values { get; }
```

to the interface.

Now, the implementation needs to have this as well but when i implement these, i get this error:

"The keyword new is required because it hides property Keys . .. "

so what do i need to do.  Should i be adding a "new" in front of these get properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option would be to change the types on the interface to be:

```
public interface IMyDictionary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    Dictionary<string, IFoo>.KeyCollection Keys { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    Dictionary<string, IFoo>.ValueCollection Values { get; }
}
```

That way the interface is already implemented by the dictionary saving you the trouble of implementing the properties again, and it doesn't hide or cover the original implementation.

Comment: I get this error: Error 2 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,ClassLibrary1.IFoo>.KeyCollection' is less accessible than property 'ClassLibrary1.IMyDictionary.Keys'

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Make sure IFoo is public too.

Comment: And the IMyDictionary interface aswell

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary<string, IFoo> implements the IDictionary<TKey,TValue> interface which already provides the Keys and Values properties. There shouldn't be a need to create your own properties, but the way to get around the compiler warning is to add the `new` keyword at the beginning of your property declarations in your class.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your keys and values properties are hiding the implementation of the keys and values properties in the Dictionary class.

EDIT:  Yes all you have to do is add the new keyword into you property.  So you code will look somthing like this:

```
class IFoo
{ }

interface MyDictionary
{
    ICollection<string> Keys { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerable<IFoo> Values { get; }
}

class IStuff : Dictionary<string, IFoo>, MyDictionary
{
    #region MyDictionary Members

    //Note the new keyword.
    public new ICollection<string> Keys
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public new IEnumerable<IFoo> Values
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I would still recommend implementing IDictionary though.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use explicit interface implementation. That way if someone is referencing MyDictionary by using the interface IMyDictionary they will see the methods and nothing else. I would also recommend implementing IDictionary instead. Unless you want to restrict usage to just Keys and Values.

```
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, IFoo>, IMyDictionary
{
    ICollection<string> IMyDictionary.Keys
    {
        get { return Keys; }
    }

    IEnumerable<IFoo> IMyDictionary.Values
    {
        get { return Values; }
    }
}
```